# How to test different Android OSs on physical hardware?

Tags: android, android-testing

I wish to test my Android application against different versions of the Android OS on physical hardware. The need comes from testing interactions of my program with 3rd party hardware (barcode scanners).

In order to "switch" between Android OSs, I assume in order to "reimage" my phone, that I will have to root the phone then set the particular OS version with various images.

There seems to be much discussion on how to root the phones, however I'm curious if there is a easy/standard way to do this for developers (e.g. standard hardware which allows for this process to happen quickly/easily)? If not, how can I proceed?

Comment: It may not be ideal, but I always hop on Craigslist or some other site like that and find cheap, unused devices.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, other than rooting your phone and flashing it w/ various OSs, you don't have a lot of options.  My company keeps a tone of devices on hand running various different versions of android to address this exact challenge.

Otherwise, there are services out there that may be of help to you.  Take a look at these:

> http://www.deviceanywhere.com/
>
> http://www.perfectomobile.com/

I'm sure there are others as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a testing of release candidate (not your BAU testing development), you may publish your app on Google Play as closed beta and then ask your friends (or some other community you trust) to play with the app.